# Braintree iOS: fatal error 'Braintree_Configuration' not found

Tags: php, ios, braintree

I want to integrate Braintree payment in my iOS app. For this I have installed composer following https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md.

The composer folder is created locally and I have put it on my server.

But when I run `payAmountUsingBraintree.php` file, I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Braintree_Configuration' not found`

Contents of `payAmountUsingBraintree.php`:

```
    <?php
//include '../config.php';
include 'db_config.php';
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
//echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();

$PartnerId = $_POST["PartnerId"];
$nonce = $_POST["Nonce"];
$amount = $_POST["Amount"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];
$SaveCard = $_POST["SaveCard"];
$number = $_POST["CardNumber"];
$postal_code = $_POST["postal_code"];
$CVV = $_POST["CVV"];
$MerchantAccountId = '';
$IsAvailable = 'no';



Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox'); // get error on this line
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('2qyx6qtd9bvy82r');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('c9qvxk3nvhmd68b');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('6f8ca01bd95cc0c753e936148303de4');
```

Where am I getting wrong? How do I solve this?

Comment: I work at Braintree. Sorry we missed your question. If you've solved it, can you post an answer and let me know? Otherwise, I suggest you [email our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/); they'll be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

I know its a bit late. But let me add the solution for future readers who might be looking for similar solution while integrating the **PHP** technology to get the client token.

You need to setup the prerequisites first.

- PHP version >= 5.4.0 is required.

The following PHP extensions are required:

- curl
- dom
- hash
- openssl
- xmlwriter

Assuming that you have installed the dependencies on your server. BrainTree API expect the followings:

1) A Developer Sandbox Account – Create one [here](https://www.braintreepayments.com/sandbox)

2) BrainTree Client Framework within your application – Download from [here](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php)

**Quick Start Example**

```
<?php

require_once 'PATH_TO_BRAINTREE/lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('your_merchant_id');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('your_public_key');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('your_private_key');

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
    'amount' => '1000.00',
    'paymentMethodNonce' => 'nonceFromTheClient',
    'options' => [ 'submitForSettlement' => true ]
]);

if ($result->success) {
    print_r("success!: " . $result->transaction->id);
} else if ($result->transaction) {
    print_r("Error processing transaction:");
    print_r("\n  code: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseCode);
    print_r("\n  text: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseText);
} else {
    print_r("Validation errors: \n");
    print_r($result->errors->deepAll());
}
```

The statement `require_once 'PATH_TO_BRAINTREE/lib/Braintree.php';` was missing from your code snippet.

Here are the reference links for the solution.

1) [Integrating Braintree Payment Gateway with PHP](http://www.hurricanesoftwares.com/integrating-braintree-payment-gateway-with-php/)

2) [Github link of Braintree PHP](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php)

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue. This error rises only after Braintree.php is succesfully included. But the other file i.e Braintree.php/configuration.php is not included by the **autoload.php**

This is a **Invalid Directory path** error.

You want to use exact **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** in the **$file_name** and change the

`$fileName = dirname(__DIR__) . '/lib/';`

to

`$fileName = dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'paypal'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;`

i have used paypal as the directory. so change it as you want. And try to print the full **$filename** if you get same error and correct the directory path.